# How do I select a JavaScript Object Array within an Object Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How do I select the strings in the randomImage.images array from my randomImage.imagePicker method?

```
(function() {

var randomImage = {

        images : [
                'http://placehold.it/100x100',
                'http://placehold.it/200x200',
                'http://placehold.it/300x300',
                'http://placehold.it/400x400'
                ],//images Array
        imagePicker : function () {
                return console.log(randomImage.images[2]);
                }()//imagePicker Method

}//randomImage Object

})()
```

I get the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined

Comment: Exactly like that. `randomImage.images[2]` accesses the third element in the array. Not sure what your issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined`

The problem is that you have `()` after the function definition:

```
imagePicker : function () {
    return console.log(randomImage.images[2]);
}()//imagePicker Method
 ^^
```

That will *immediately call* the function and assign its return value to `imagePicker`. But at this moment `randomImage` hasn't been initialized yet. Its value is still `undefined` and that's why you get that error.

Remove the parenthesis to assign the function itself (I assume that's what you want to do):

```
imagePicker : function () {
    return console.log(randomImage.images[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to specify the index of the randomImage you want to get:

```
imagePicker : function (idx) {
  return randomImage.images[idx];
}
```

`randomImage.imagePicker(1)` will return `http://placehold.it/200x200`

Comment: randomImage.imagePicker(1) doesn't actually work outside as its defined on a function scope!

Answer (score 0):

Provided you just want it to return a random image from the `images` array:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ncpqe3zo/)

```
imagePicker : function () {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomImage.images.length);
  return randomImage.images[index];
}
```

Returning just a specific image can be done using the index:

```
imagePicker : function () {
  // index 0 returns 'http://placehold.it/100x100'
  return randomImage.images[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the magic word:

```
    (function() {

    var randomImage = {

            images : [
                    'http://placehold.it/100x100',
                    'http://placehold.it/200x200',
                    'http://placehold.it/300x300',
                    'http://placehold.it/400x400'
                    ],//images Array
            imagePicker : function () {
                    alert(this.images[2]);
                    }//imagePicker Method

    }//randomImage Object

    randomImage.imagePicker();

 })();
```

Be aware that `randomImage` variable is not available outside of the auto-function!

Fiddle [here](http://randomImage.imagePicker();)